# Shamefully simple: need help spacing shapes

Tags: math, button, spacing

I have a simple problem that for some reason I can not manage to solve. I have a window with a height of 600 pixels (width does not matter) and buttons with a height of 90 pixels. what I need is to be able to evenly space the buttons on the screen with a variable amount of buttons. for example if I had one button it would be in the center, more than that they would be spaced apart. I've tried (600 - (90 * #ofbuttons)) / (#ofbuttons + 1) but that didn't work. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

How about simply:

```
center_of_button_i = 600*i/(n+1)
```

Comment: +1 simple solution to a simple problem (although I'm inclined not to upvote single-line answers...)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks, I've made it multi-line :)

Comment: Well...can't argue with that :p